# Phalcon $model-find()->filter + paginate

Tags: filter, model, find, phalcon

Having a look in the doc, this code works :

```
$customers = Customers::find();

$numberPage = $this->request->getQuery("page", "int");
$paginator = new Paginator(array(
    "data"  => $customers,
    "limit" => 10,
    "page"  => $numberPage
));
```

But this one doesn't work, and I really don't understand why

```
$customers = Customers::find()->filter(
  function ($customer) {

    // Return only customers with a valid e-mail
    if (filter_var($customer->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return $customer;
    }
  }
);

$numberPage = $this->request->getQuery("page", "int");
$paginator = new Paginator(array(
    "data"  => $customers,
    "limit" => 10,
    "page"  => $numberPage
));
```

Then, I get an "internal error".  Strange, $customers object seems altered.

Any idea ?

By advance, thank you.

Comment: Please post the entire error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Result of [`Model::find()`](https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model.html) should be an instance of  `Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset` what is accepted by paginator of `Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\Model`.

Result of [`Resultset::filter()`](https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Resultset.html) method is an array of model instances, what is not an instance of Resultset. To paginate arrays there is `Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\NativeArray` [paginator](https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/pagination.html#data-adapters) implemented.